# How to get the reference count on Linux driver level?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In the Linux kernel the opened file is indicated by `struct file`, and the file descriptor table contains a pointers which is point to `struct file`. `f_count` is an important member in the struct file. `f_count`, which means Reference Count. The system call `dup()` and `fork()` make other file descriptor point to same `struct file`.

As shown in the picture (sorry, my reputation is too low, the picture can not be uploaded), `fd1` and `fd2` point to the `struct file`, so the Reference Count is equal to 2, thus `f_count = 2`.

My question is how can i get the value of the `f_count` by programming.

**UPDATE**:ok,In order to make myself more clear i will show my code, both the char device driver,Makefile and my application.:D

deviceDriver.c

```
#include "linux/kernel.h"
#include "linux/module.h"
#include "linux/fs.h"
#include "linux/init.h"
#include "linux/types.h"
#include "linux/errno.h"
#include "linux/uaccess.h"
#include "linux/kdev_t.h"
#define MAX_SIZE 1024

static int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);
static int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file);
static ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *user, size_t      t, loff_t *f);
static ssize_t my_write(struct file *file, const char __user *user, size_t t, loff_t *f);

static char message[MAX_SIZE] = "-------congratulations--------!";
static int device_num = 0;//device number
static int counter = 0;
static int mutex = 0;
static char* devName = "myDevice";//device name

struct file_operations pStruct =
{ open:my_open, release:my_release, read:my_read, write:my_write, };

/* regist the module */
int init_module()
{
    int ret;
    /  **/
   ret = register_chrdev(0, devName, &pStruct);
if (ret < 0)
{
    printk("regist failure!\n");
    return -1;
}
else
{
    printk("the device has been registered!\n");
    device_num = ret;
    printk("<1>the virtual device's major number %d.\n", device_num);
    printk("<1>Or you can see it by using\n");
    printk("<1>------more /proc/devices-------\n");
    printk("<1>To talk to the driver,create a dev file with\n");
    printk("<1>------'mknod /dev/myDevice c %d 0'-------\n", device_num);
    printk("<1>Use \"rmmode\" to remove the module\n");

    return 0;
}
}

void cleanup_module()
{
    unregister_chrdev(device_num, devName);
   printk("unregister it success!\n");
}

static int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    if(mutex)
            return -EBUSY;
    mutex = 1;//lock
    printk("<1>main  device : %d\n", MAJOR(inode->i_rdev));
    printk("<1>slave device : %d\n", MINOR(inode->i_rdev));
    printk("<1>%d times to call the device\n", ++counter);
    try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);
    return 0;
}
/* release */
static int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    printk("Device released!\n");
    module_put(THIS_MODULE);
    mutex = 0;//unlock
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *user, size_t t, loff_t *f)
{
    if(copy_to_user(user,message,sizeof(message)))
    {
      return -EFAULT;
    }
    return sizeof(message);
}

static ssize_t my_write(struct file *file, const char __user *user, size_t t, loff_t *f)
{
    if(copy_from_user(message,user,sizeof(message)))
    {
       return -EFAULT;
    }
    return sizeof(message);
}
```

Makefile:

```
# If KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the
# kernel build system and can use its language.
ifeq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
# Assume the source tree is where the running kernel was built
# You should set KERNELDIR in the environment if it's elsewhere
KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
# The current directory is passed to sub-makes as argument
PWD := $(shell pwd)
modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules_install
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions
.PHONY: modules modules_install clean
else
    # called from kernel build system: just declare what our modules are
    obj-m := devDrv.o
endif
```

application.c:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char buf[MAX_SIZE];
    char get[MAX_SIZE];
    char devName[20], dir[50] = "/dev/";
    system("ls /dev/");
    printf("Please input the device's name you wanna to use :");
    gets(devName);
    strcat(dir, devName);
    fd = open(dir, O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd != -1)
    {
        read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("The device was inited with a string : %s\n", buf);
        /* test fot writing */
        printf("Please input a string  :\n");
        gets(get);
        write(fd, get, sizeof(get));
        /* test for reading */
       read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)); 
       system("dmesg");
       printf("\nThe string in the device now is : %s\n", buf);
       close(fd);
       return 0;
  }
  else
  {
      printf("Device open failed\n");
      return -1;
  }
}
```

Any idea to get the `struct file`'s(char device file) `f_count`? Is it poassible get it by the way of `printk`?

Comment: Please rephrase your question and apply some formating it's very unclear.

Comment: sorry for my bad expression,i have rephrased my question to make myself clear thx :D

Answer (score 2):

You should divide reference counter to module from other module and from user-space application. `lsmod` show how many modules use your module.

```
sctp                  247143  4 
libcrc32c              12644  1 sctp
```

It is impossible load `sctp` without `libcrc32c` because `sctp` use exported function from `libcrc32` to calculate control sum for packets. 
The reference counter itself is embedded in the module data structure and can be obtained with the function `uint module_refcount(struct module* module);`

You can use:

```
printk("Module reference counter: %d\n", (int)module_refcount(THIS_MODULE));
```

`THIS_MODULE` it is a reference to current loadable module (for build-in module it is NULL) inside `.owner` field (inside `struct file_operations`).

If there is a need manually modify module's counter use:

```
int try_module_get(struct module* module);
void module_put(struct module* module);
```

If module unloaded it will return `false`. You also can move thru all modules. Modules linked via list.

File opening inside kernel it is bad idea. Inside kernel you can get access to `inode`. Try read man pages for `dup` and `fork`. In you system you can investigate `lsof` tools.

Comment: thanks in advance...but i am afraid not make myself clear.so i would like to give you a real scene to the program:i worte a linux deive driver of the char device.(of course i add the deivce file to /dev), and then i wrote a application to read and write the char deivce.Yes, it works well.so, can i get the value of f_count of the struct file?NOTE:f_count is one of the members in the struct file.NOT the reference count of the module...i will give my code later :D thx